# Exim forward router

Tags: mysql, forward, exim

I am trying to create an exim router where the `from` and the `to` headers are being fetched from a mysql database.
As I can not find much documentation about using such a forwarder for non-existing domains on the local server I am quite stuck.

I have the following router where only the receiving mail account is being matched at the moment:

```
virtual_user_fwd:
        driver                  = redirect
        verify                  = no
        data                    = ${lookup mysql{SELECT adress FROM mail_forwards WHERE host = '${quote_mysql:$domain}' AND fwd IS NOT NULL} {${sg{$value}{\\n}{, }}}}
```

I need the next step: Somewhere/Somehow where I define the mail account where the mails are forwarded to.
Is there anyone who can help me get to the next step?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a new way to create the mysql link

```
virtual_userforward:
        driver = redirect
        verify = no
        data = ${lookup mysql { SELECT goto FROM mail_forwards WHERE adress='${local_part}@${domain}'}}
        domains = *
```

This seems to work for the virtual test, however when testing an email I get an error 'unroutable adress'. Any ideas?